# How many 240 volt fluorescent fixtures can I connect to a 30 amp breaker?

Tags: electrical, light-fixture

How many 240 volt fluorescent (2 X 4 recessed, 4 tubes) fixtures can I connect to a 30 amp breaker using 4 mmsq cable?

Comment: What is the wattage of these lamps?

Comment: What country are you in?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like europe?  Total Wattage divided by voltage = Amps  or Volts x Amps = Watts.  so 240V x 30A= 7200W.  I would personally not hit that 7200 total watts and have the circuit totally loaded.  so the wattage of the lamps is the determining factor as Niall said.

Comment: fluorescent are more power hungry on startup so add a good safety margin to that